# Increase date's month by interval in the model field within filter

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting objects like this. date_from, date_to are input variables

```
result = Records.objects.filter(recorddate__range=(date_from, date_to))
```

There is another integer variable off_set. How can I use it in filter like this
so the month of recorddate field is increased by off_set numbers. Like

```
result = Records.objects.filter((recorddate+off_set)__range=(date_from, date_to))
```

Comment: What about adding it to both `date_from` and `date_to`?

Comment: Is the `off_set` integer always the number of _months_ to add?

Comment: AS @toti08 mentioned, if you want to check if a `date + offset` is within a `range`, you can also check that `date` is in the `range - offset`.

Comment: Yes the off_set  is always int num of months. Actually is is coming from another Model and may vary record to record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could subtract the offset from the range to filter the relevant records.

Creating the offset could be slightly tricky, due to the fact that months have differing numbers of days (Python's `timedelta` doesn't support months).

For this you might consider `dateutil.relativedelta()`, although this would require a separate `pip install python-dateutil`. You'd also need to ensure that `date_from` and `date_to` were converted to `datetime` objects if they weren't already. For example:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

months = relativedelta(months=off_set)
result = Records.objects.filter(recorddate__range=(date_from - months, date_to - months))
```